# Unable to reach Hortonworks HDP on port 8080:This site can't be reached

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding, hadoop

My goal is to run HDP on VM VirtualBox

Image shows my port forwarding rules

[image]

When I try to launch dashboard
[image]

My host machine is 18.04 Ubuntu.

```
Port mapping output
8000/tcp  open  http-alt
8042/tcp  open  fs-agent
8081/tcp  open  blackice-icecap
8082/tcp  open  blackice-alerts
8086/tcp  open  d-s-n
8088/tcp  open  radan-http
```

I killed the Jenkins process that was active before.
If I goto

```
http://localhost:1080/splash2.html
```

that points to advanced HDP quick links and choose zeppelin for example

```
502 Bag GateWay
nginx/1.15.7
```

How to solve this problem?